# Can I use handler instead of webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, httphandler

I have a stiuation where I have to decide what should I use a `http-handler` or a `web-service`.

I want to expose some kind of method for particular people who will use this.

The senerio is one of my client has to install `.apk` file on his `tab` to access my application. 
 Inside that file my asp.net application is called. 
Before accessing my application there is a registration process for which I need some method to register that device. 
 I have used `http-handler` which is working fine for me in `testing`.
Will it can cause some problem in future.
They are writing code for sending hitting my `handler` and gettin back result from there. It is running fine in `testing`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use handler instead of webservice.

> Will it cause problems ?

Anything can cause new problems. It all depends on what You need and what Your skills\experience is.

This may bring more light:

[Difference asp.net web service and Ihttphandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495344/difference-asp-net-web-service-and-ihttphandler)